# How can I dynamically add values to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn angular, and I have an example code snippet that is the following:

```
$scope.contents = [{
    name: 'Chris Doe',
    abbreviation: 'Developer',
},{
    name: 'Ann Doe',
    abbreviation: 'Commerce',
},{
    name: 'Mark Ronson',
    abbreviation: 'Designer',
},{
    name: 'Eric Doe',
    abbreviation: 'Human Resources',
},{
    name: 'John Doe',
    abbreviation: 'Commerce',
},{
    name: 'George Doe',
    abbreviation: 'Media',
},{
    name: 'Ann Ronson',
    abbreviation: 'Commerce',
},{
    name: 'Adam Ronson',
    abbreviation: 'Developer',
},{
    name: 'Hansel Doe',
    abbreviation: 'Social Media',
},{
    name: 'Tony Doe',
    abbreviation: 'CEO',
}];
```

Which works fine, but I want to fetch data from an API and then load the data into the `$scope.contents`. I have tried the following:

```
$http(req).success(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        console.log(res[i]);
        //add data into scope contents here .add(res[i])
    }
}).error(function (err) { console.log(err) });
```

and this works, I am able to loop through the object of data returned from my API, however I cannot figure out the syntax to add the returned data into `$scope.contents` What is the proper way to do this? Is there a better way to do this? Like making `$scope.contents` a class and adding the data as a new instance?

Comment: Can you share the format of the response data. An example of what `console.log(res[I]);` outputs would be great.

Comment: @JRulle `Object { id: 2, name: "Germany", abbreviation: "DE" }`

Comment: Given that format, you can use @andrewR's answer below to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
$scope.contents = $scope.contents.concat(res);
```

Obviously you first want to make sure that `$scope.contents` is already an array:

```
if (! Array.isArray($scope.contents)) {
  $scope.contents = [];
}
$scope.contents = $scope.contents.concat(res);
```

Comment: Well hell, that was really easy.

Answer (score 2):

`$scope.contents` is an array, so you can push a new object to it.

```
$http(req).success(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        console.log(res[i]);
        $scope.contents.push(res[i]);
    }
}).error(function (err) { console.log(err) });
```

It's not obvious from your example what `res[i]` contains. The above code is assuming that it is already the correct object. If not, take this and place the correct values.

```
$scope.contents.push({
    name: res[i].name,
    abbreviation: res[i].abbreviation,
}); // example -- change to match your data
```

Answer (score 1):

$scope.contents looks like an array so...

```
$scope.contents.push(res[i]);
```